# Python Permission Denied with ffprobe on NamedTemporaryFile

Tags: python, django, windows

I'm trying to validate certain parameters of a media file before the file gets saved in Django.  So I validate the file using ffprobe (from the ffmpeg pip package).

```
with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=f'.{self.audio.name.split(".")[-1]}') as fp:
    fp.write(self.audio.read())
    try:
        # Get duration with ffprobe
        info = probe(fp.name)
        self.duration = info['format']['duration']
        fp.close()
    except ffmpeg.Error as e:
        print('stderr:', e.stderr.decode('utf8'))
        raise NotAudioFile
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise NotAudioFile
```

This is the snippet that validates the file.  `self.audio` is a Django FileField.  It creates a named temporary file, writes the file from the django file, and then validates it using ffprobe.

However, when it runs, ffprobe gives me a Permission Denied error, which is weird, since I checked the file and I have full permission to write that directory/file.

```
stderr: ffprobe version 4.3.2-2021-02-20-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsr
t --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --ena
ble-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme
--enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
C:\Users\cclloyd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9lhjsl9n.mp3: Permission denied
```

So why is it giving me that error?

Comment: Show the traceback.

Comment: definitely looks like a local file/directory permissions error.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile):

> ...name can be retrieved from the `name` attribute of the returned
> file-like object. Whether the `name` can be used to open the file a
> second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies
> across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; **it cannot on Windows NT
> or later**). If `delete` is `true` (**the default**), the file is deleted as
> soon as it is closed.

When you pass `fp.name` to `probe()` function, the [`ffprobe` process](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/ffmpeg/_probe.py#L20) attempts to access/open the file, but - as described above and [here](https://github.com/bravoserver/bravo/issues/111#issuecomment-826990) - Windows does not allow processes other than the one used to create the `NamedTemporaryFile` to access the file when the `delete` is set to `True`. Thus, you should set `delete` to `False` when creating a new instance of a `NamedTemporaryFile`, and delete the file once you are done with it using the `os.remove()` or `os.unlink()` method. Example below:

```
f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=f'.{self.audio.name.split(".")[-1]}')
try:
    f.write(self.audio.read())
    try:
        # Get duration with ffprobe
        info = probe(f.name)
        self.duration = info['format']['duration']
    except ffmpeg.Error as e:
        print('stderr:', e.stderr.decode('utf8'))
        raise NotAudioFile
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise NotAudioFile
finally:
    f.close()
    os.remove(f.name)  # delete the file
```