# fastapi websocket recieve_bytes and processes the bytes to a temporary audio file

Tags: python, audio, websocket, byte, fastapi

IDK How to process bytes data from the data variable to make a temporary audio file to be processed into speech_recognition

````
@router.websocket('/change-voice/{speakerId}/{bahasaYangDigunakan}')
async def change_voice(
    websocket: WebSocket,
    speakerId: int,
    BahasaYangDigunakan: int,
    access_token: Annotated[str| None, Cookie()] = None,
    ):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
        # procress bytes from data to a temporary audio file
        audio_file = blablablabala
        with sr.AudioFile(audio_file.file) as audio_file:
            audio_data = r.record(audio_file)
            transcript = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language=BahasaYangDigunakan)```
````

i want process bytes data from the data variable to make a temporary audio file to be processedinto speech_recognition

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766160/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Also, please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324461/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71457439/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71377044/17865804)